# Dados sobreescritos ao gravar log de acessos em arquivo

Tags: php

Estou com um problema que creio ser de fácil solução, mas não sei como resolver.

Abaixo segue um script para gravar quem acessou a página. Funcionou legal, mas ele sobrescreve um acesso em cima do outro, e eu preciso que cada IP que acessou fique gravado, um embaixo do outro.

Além disso não sei como acertar o horário, está aparecendo com 5 horas a mais.

```
<?php
   /* se o arquivo não existir, será criado, dê
      permissão 777 na pasta onde ele será criado */
   $arquivo = "includes/spy.txt"; // arquivo que gravará os dados
   $data = date("d/m/Y H:i:s"); // Data do acesso
   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // IP de acesso
   $host = getHostByAddr($ip); // Host de acesso
   $pagina = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // Página de acesso
   $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // Browser de acesso
   $fp = fopen($arquivo, "w+");
   fwrite( $fp,
      "Data: $data | IP: $ip | host: $host | Pagina Acessada: $pagina | Navegador: $browser"
   );
   fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Mude o [modo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php) do `fopen` para `a` (*append*):

```
$fp = fopen($arquivo, 'a+');
```

veja a diferença das flags do `fopen` no [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php) (destaquei os pontos chave):

> `w+`    Abre para leitura e escrita; **coloca o ponteiro do arquivo no começo do arquivo e reduz o comprimento do arquivo para zero**. Se o arquivo não existir, tenta criá-lo.
>
> `a+`    Abre para leitura e escrita; **coloca o ponteiro do arquivo no final do arquivo**. Se o arquivo não existir, tenta criá-lo.

Quanto à data, o problema provavelmente é o *[timezone](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.php)* do servidor. A linha abaixo deve resolver (use antes do `date`):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); // Europe/Lisbon
```

Comment: Meu amigo, muitissimo obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Oi Diego. Legal, se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema, você pode marcá-la como "aceita" clicando no ícone que tem embaixo da pontuação da resposta. Mais detalhes em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
       /* se o arquivo não existir, será criado, dê
          permissão 777 na pasta onde ele será criado */
       date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
       $arquivo = "includes/spy.txt"; // arquivo que gravará os dados
       $data = date("d/m/Y H:i:s"); // Data do acesso
       $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // IP de acesso
       $host = getHostByAddr($ip); // Host de acesso
       $pagina = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // Página de acesso
       $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // Browser de acesso
       $fp = fopen($arquivo, "a+");
       fwrite( $fp,
          "Data: $data | IP: $ip | host: $host | Pagina Acessada: $pagina | Navegador: $browser"."\r\n"
       );
       fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

**OU**

```
<?php
   /* se o arquivo não existir, será criado, dê
      permissão 777 na pasta onde ele será criado */
   date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
   $arquivo = "includes/spy.txt"; // arquivo que gravará os dados
   $data = date("d/m/Y H:i:s"); // Data do acesso
   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // IP de acesso
   $host = getHostByAddr($ip); // Host de acesso
   $pagina = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // Página de acesso
   $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // Browser de acesso
   $fp = fopen($arquivo, "a+");
   fwrite( $fp,
      "Data: $data | IP: $ip | host: $host | Pagina Acessada: $pagina | Navegador: $browser"."\r\n"."\r\n"
   );
   fclose($fp);
?>
```